# I cannot get the numbers in theorem environment (thmtools)

Tags: thmtools

I can't seem to get the numbers of my theorems back in my custom theorem environment, some help would be appreciated:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,nameref}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, 
spacebelow=6pt, 
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
notefont=\em\mdseries, 
notebraces={(}{)}, 
headpunct={},
bodyfont=\itshape, 
headformat=\NAME\ \NOTE\\\@afterheading,
]{theorem}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[style=theorem,
numbered=yes,
name=Theorem, 
refname={theorem,theorem}, 
Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}
First theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Second theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{theorem}
Third theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply format to add the `\NUMBER` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,nameref}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,
spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\em\mdseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct={},
bodyfont=\itshape,
headformat=\NAME\,\textcolor{red}{\NUMBER}\NOTE\\\@afterheading,
]{theorem}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[style=theorem,
numbered=yes,
name=Theorem,
refname={theorem,theorem},
Refname={Theorem,Theorems}]{theorem}

\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\begin{theorem}[First trial]
First theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Second theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{theorem}
Third theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So if I want to use the same theoremstyle for theorems and say propositions I would need to create a copy of the style whithout the number command?

Comment: Because you don't want them to be numbered?

Comment: Yes, my question should have been: Is there a way to put the \NUMBER command in the \declaretheorem instead of \declaretheoremstyle.

Comment: It seems the `headformat` key is known only to `\declaretheoremstyle`, so I think it isn't possible. See the keys known to `\declaretheorem` in §3.2 of the documentation, pp. 14-15.

Comment: Okay merci beaucoup pour votre aide!